# Vim auto-formating code Allman style

Tags: 16.04, vim

I'm asking this question since the internet seems full of incomplete guides on how to do this task.

I'm looking for a way to format my entire file Allman style (braces on their own lines, 4 spaces, no tabs) at a press of a button.

Comment: For four spaces, you can give `:set shiftwidth=4`. If you don't want tabs, you can give `:retab`. You can put these in vimrc file. You can map them to a key.  I am not sure how to lit braces on their own lines, may be with substitute. Can you given one example for braces on their lines, one sample and one expected output of code?

Comment: curl brackets on their own line sort of thing, also I put :set as is in the vimrc?

Comment: yes. put it in vimrc. You may try search and replace for curly braces, like `:%s/{/\r{/g`.